# Json.Net reads and tries to instantiate custom attributes on the type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization, custom-attributes

I have a Web Api project sharing its models with internal customers, such as this:

```
public PaymentController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpAction PostPayment(PaymentRequest request)
    {
    }
}

[Validator(typeof(PaymentRequestValidator))]
public class PaymentRequest
{
}
```

Where we're using FluentValidation to validate incoming requests:

```
public class PaymentRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<PaymentRequest>
{
}
```

When a client makes a call:

```
httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/payment", new PaymentRequest());
```

Json.Net reads and tries to instantiate custom attributes on the type. Since we don't ship FluentValidation alongside with the models it causes an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Stack trace:

```
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ReflectionUtils.GetAttributes(Object attributeProvider, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAssociateMetadataTypeFromAttribute(Type type)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.AddValue(TKey key)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.Get(TKey key)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute[T](Type type)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.AddValue(TKey key)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.Get(TKey key)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.WriteStartArray(JsonWriter writer, Object values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Is it possible to avoid that? In other way than ship them together.

Comment: Possibly a custom contract resolver?

Comment: @zaitsman: will try next week, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create two different copies of the PaymentRequest class implementing the same interface, in separate namespaces. Maybe something like this:

```
public interface IPaymentRequest 
{
}

//This class will be shipped to your clients. 
public class PaymentRequestDTO: IPaymentRequest
{
} 


//This class will be used in your WebAPI or Server Side code.
[Validator(typeof(PaymentRequestValidator))]
public class PaymentRequest: IPaymentRequest
{
}
```

Then you only need to ship the DTO class for all your clients, but use your internal implementation with your validator on un server side.